# Blade is not working on laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is what I have written in my view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">

        {{Hi everyone}}

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It outputs **{{Hi everyone}}**

why is it not working ?

Answer (score 2):

First: The view file should be named with a ".blade.php" after it.

Second: The `{{ $str }}` blade command it's only a shortcut to `<?php echo $str ?>`. That been said, if you want to just print a string, you should put it between `"` or even `'`, as you would probably do with a regular `echo` statement. Something like `echo "Hi everyone";`.

That SHOULD work on your case! :D

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be renamed as filename.blade.php. Check if the file had been named as per the convention rules.

Comment: Have you added the path in the laravel routes file?

Answer (score 0):

You should call it in your route or controller with `return View::make("hello");` etc. Also @Its Aafrin described, your file needs to be renamed as `filename.blade.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There are diffrent ways to print. However you are just missing  quotes. I have listed other methods also...
 1. `{{'Hi every one'}}`
 2. `<?php $str='hi every one' ?>  {{$str}}`
 3. `<?= 'Hi every one' ?>`